# SendGrid SMTP error {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."}

Tags: smtp, sendgrid, smtpclient

This might seem to be duplicate but it is not. I tried restarting the IIS, enclosing the SMTPClient in the using block etc. But Still I'm getting the error.

```
try
{
   //I have replaced sender@gmail.com and receiver@gmail.com by a valid gmail addresses
    MailAddress sender = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");
    MailAddress receiver = new MailAddress("receiver@gmail.com");
    MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage(sender, receiver);
    mailMsg.Subject = "subject";

    string text = "text body";
    string html = @"<p>html body</p>";

    mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text,  null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
    mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));


    using(SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
           smtpClient.Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
           smtpClient.Port = 587;
           smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

          //UserName = Username of SendGrid account, Password = Password of SendGrid account
           System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "password");
           smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
           smtpClient.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1; /* without this the connection is idle too long and not terminated, times out at the server and gives sequencing errors */

           smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);            

         }            
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }

catch (Exception ex)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
```

This is a MVC application developed in VS 2015.

Any input on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I didn't notice I had put the wrong username in the web.config settings

Answer (score 0):

You can see SendGrid configuration for SMTP by going to **Setup -> Guide -> Integrate SMTP** after login into https://app.sendgrid.com

Comment: I have the same problem.  I can send an email from my laptop when testing locally, but get the error when attempting to send from the server.

On SendGrid, I navigated to Email Activity.  You can add search filters, I used the default: the last 4 days.  Next, I clicked on a message that was **not delivered**  From there, expanding the details revealed that: 

> 530 IP 149.**.***.**4 denied access to SMTP at 06/01/22 07:06:23